# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'event' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm new to Laravel, I have this strange error in my API.

In `AttendeeController`, using `Events $event` as an argument throws an error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'event' in 'where clause'

But using `string id` and querying the event, works. Any ideas?

Below is the full code for context.

##### `AttendeeController`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Resources\AttendeeResource;
use App\Models\Attendee;
use App\Models\Event;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AttendeeController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Event $event)
    {
        $attendees = $event->attendees()->latest();

        return AttendeeResource::collection($attendees->paginate(10));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     */
    public function store(string $id, Request $request)
    {
        $event = Event::findOrFail($id);
        $attendee = $event->attendees()->create([
            'user_id' => 1,
        ]);

        return new AttendeeResource($attendee);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     */
    public function show(string $event_id, Attendee $attendee)
    {
        return new AttendeeResource($attendee);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     */
    public function update(Request $request, string $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     */
    public function destroy(string $id, Attendee $attendee)
    {
        $attendee->delete();

        return response()->noContent();
    }
}
```

##### `EventController`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Resources\EventResource;
use App\Models\Event;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class EventController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     */
    // set id as the primary key

    public function index()
    {
        return EventResource::collection(Event::with('user')->paginate(10));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $event = Event::create([
            ...$request->validate([
                'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
                'description' => ['nullable', 'string', 'max:255'],
                'start_date' => ['required', 'date'],
                'end_date' => ['required', 'date', 'after:start_date'],
            ]),
            'user_id' => 1,
        ]);

        return new EventResource($event);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     */
    public function show(Event $event)
    {
        $event->load('user', 'attendees');
        return new EventResource($event);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Event $event)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => ['sometimes', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'description' => ['nullable', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'start_date' => ['sometimes', 'date'],
            'end_date' => ['sometimes', 'date', 'after:start_date'],
        ]);

        $event->update([...$request->all()]);

        return new EventResource($event);
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     */
    public function destroy(Event $event)
    {
        $event->delete();

        return response()->noContent();
    }
}
```

##### `api.php`

```php
Route::apiResource('events', EventController::class);
Route::apiResource('events.attendees', AttendeeController::class)
    ->scoped()->except(['update']);
```

I'm expecting that laravel should be able to use the `id` on the `Event $event` in the `AttendeeController` like it does on the the `EventController`

Comment: It's an SQL error, column is missing from table, as the message clearly says

Comment: When you pass a parameter trough a URL on Laravel, in the controller it will expect the same name as you set it in your URL, so if in your URL you pass a parameter called `event` for example, but in the controller you expect an `$id` it will not work, you need to set the variable for the parameter you're expecting to receive, with the same name `$event` for example. `EventController` works because it's expecting `Event $event`, not `string $id`

Comment: So as per your question, yes given a string id to your `index()` of AttendeeController will work, but if you wish to use type hint `Event $event` then you need to adjust your route something like this `scoped(['event' => 'id'])`

Comment: All your generated routes trough your nested route will look like `/api/events/{event}/attendees` for example, so, in your controller it will be expecting for that `$event` name, instead of `$id` or `$event_id`

Comment: @ZeNix Thanks, you are right. I just saw a similar answer and fixed it according. Route-Model binding expects the same "variable name" as the URL in this case `events` instead of `event`.